# CodeContracts reporting precision mismatch between two doubles

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Given the following C# code,

```
double x = 2.0;
x *= 0.5;
bool y = (x == 1.0);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

CodeContracts gives a warning: `Possible precision mismatch for the arguments of ==`.

If I change the code to any of the following:

```
double x = 2.0 * 0.5;
bool y = (x == 1.0);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

or

```
double x = 2.0 * 0.5;
bool y;
if (x == 1.0) {
  y = true;
} else {
  y = false;
}
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

or, perhaps most confusingly

```
double x = 2.0;
x *= 0.5;
bool y = ((double)x == 1.0);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

it doesn't give me any warning. What makes the first case different to the others that it deserves a warning?

### Update

Just another example of this warning being produced, this time as a guard for a division operator:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(rhs != 0.0);
```

Comment: I don't know why CodeContracts complains in just that one case, but in general why it's right to complain about stuff like that is explained in detail in [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @TimS. It is allowed to complain about this sort of thing, and usually I wouldn't test for float equality after a calculation, but in this case it was for checking whether to use the singular or plural form of a word following the number, so I really do need to check that it's exactly one.

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4294f31-2bee-4e9b-8594-199aea6ff59e/false-warning-possible-precision-mismatch-for-the-arguments-of-?forum=codecontracts. Is `x` actually a parameter, or a local variable?

Comment: @TimS. `x` actually is a local variable, both in the sample above and in the original code. I did see that MSDN post earlier, and that's where I got the idea for the `(double)x` version. I suppose the 80=>64 bit conversion would explain why that one works, but I'm still confused by the second non-warning case.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
double x = 2.0 * 0.5;
```

Is probably never even executed at run-time; it will just be simplified by the compiler to

```
double x = 1.0;
```

Also, checking for equality still doesn't guarantee whether or not the value is "exactly one". Consider this:

```
double x = 100000000000.0;
x*= 0.00000000001;
Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints "1"
bool y = ((double)x == 1.0);
Console.WriteLine(y); // Prints "False"
```

Comment: Yeah, I did consider your second point after I asked the question - it now writes the number to a string, parses it back and decides if it's equal to one (and that is an exact equality). CodeContracts still complains after doing that, though.

Comment: @Philip Why does it matter whether `x` is exactly one? Floating point (i.e. float or double) is useful when representing real-world values, where a billionth of a second rounding error shouldn't throw off a physics simulation. If you care about exactness, then don't use floating point at all! Instead you can use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) for exact comparisons.

Comment: @CarlWalsh For grammatical correctness - the value's going to be shown to the user with the units following, so it'd be nice to have the right plurality on the units (1.0 second, rather than 1.0 seconds).

Comment: @PhilipC Interesting! For showing output to users, instead of conditionally pluralizing the output based on Double.Equals(1.0), can you use String.Equals("1")?

Comment: @CarlWalsh I could, but it might also be displayed as "1.0", "1.00", etc. depending on the string formatting at the time. I suppose it could be regexed, but the parse-and-equate seems simpler.